# Installing a patch for a dependent module: cpanm still tries to install broken module after I have installed patched module manually

Tags: perl, cpanm

I am trying to install `Net::SSH::Perl` using `cpanm` (from `perlbrew` and `perl` version 5.30). The installation fails with:

```
$ cpanm Net::SSH::Perl
--> Working on Net::SSH::Perl
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/S/SC/SCHWIGON/Net-SSH-Perl-2.14.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Net-SSH-Perl-2.14 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Crypt::Curve25519
--> Working on Crypt::Curve25519
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/A/AJ/AJGB/Crypt-Curve25519-0.06.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Crypt-Curve25519-0.06 ... OK
Building and testing Crypt-Curve25519-0.06 ... FAIL
! Installing Crypt::Curve25519 failed. See /home/hakon/.cpanm/work/1587758019.381709/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Missing version info for module 'Crypt::Curve25519'
! Bailing out the installation for Net-SSH-Perl-2.14.
```

The problem with installing `Crypt::Curve25519` is described in [this](https://github.com/ajgb/crypt-curve25519/issues/9) issue. I downloaded the problematic module `Crypt::Curve25519` and patched it:

```
git clone git@github.com:ajgb/crypt-curve25519.git
wget https://www.cpan.org/authors/id/S/SR/SREZIC/patches/Crypt-Curve25519-0.06-PR10-ANOTHERLINK.patch
cd crypt-curve25519
git apply ../Crypt-Curve25519-0.06-PR10-ANOTHERLINK.patch
perl Makefile.PL
make  # No errors now
make test
make install
```

However, when I try again to install `Crypt::Curve25519` it still tries to install the broken module from CPAN:

```
$ cpanm Net::SSH::Perl
--> Working on Net::SSH::Perl
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/S/SC/SCHWIGON/Net-SSH-Perl-2.14.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Net-SSH-Perl-2.14 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Crypt::Curve25519
--> Working on Crypt::Curve25519
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/A/AJ/AJGB/Crypt-Curve25519-0.06.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Crypt-Curve25519-0.06 ... OK
Building and testing Crypt-Curve25519-0.06 ... FAIL
! Installing Crypt::Curve25519 failed. See /home/hakon/.cpanm/work/1587758833.382749/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Missing version info for module 'Crypt::Curve25519'
! Bailing out the installation for Net-SSH-Perl-2.14.
```

How can I make `cpanm` use the installed patch instead (i.e. skip installation of `Crypt::Curve25519` since it is already installed)?

Comment: Oops, already deleted comment cause I saw you found the problem.

Comment: Will the cpan command work in place of cpanm? I installed App::cpanminus and did *not* get cpanm.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things to check:

- cpanm knows where to find your patched version.
- The patched version has a version that's higher than the one on CPAN. The module idea in CPAN assumes that you always want the latest, so ensure that yours is.
- You don't want to install a patched module at the standard location because you don't want a cpan client to overwrite it.

Some other things that can work:

- Force install the module and ignore the failures (cpanm has a `--notest` feature). The CPAN version is still installed, but that doesn't matter.
- Have your patched version in a separate directory that's at the front of `@INC` so your program finds it first. This effectively hides the CPAN version.

Comment: *"cpanm knows where to find your patched version"* : I installed the patch with `make install` and it ended up at the standard location in `/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/lib/site_perl/5.30.0` so I still does not understand why `cpanm` cannot see that it is already installed

Comment: The version numbers are also the same, but there was a warning when running `perl Makefile.PL` : *"WARNING: Setting VERSION via file 'lib/Crypt/Curve25519.pm' failed"*

Comment: *"..but there was a warning.."* : and that seems to be the issue. I added a line `our $VERSION = 0.06;` to the file `lib/Crypt/Curve25519.pm` and reinstalled it. Now `cpanm Net::SSH::Perl` completed successfully!

Comment: Feel free to update your answer with the above information

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be missing `VERSION` information in the module. By adding a line

```
our $VERSION = 0.06;
```

to the top of the file `lib/Crypt/Curve25519.pm` and then reinstall, and then installing `cpanm Net::SSH::Perl` worked fine (it accepted the patched installation and did not try to download the broken version).

Here is the patch I used to `lib/Crypt/Curve25519.pm`:

```
diff --git a/lib/Crypt/Curve25519.pm b/lib/Crypt/Curve25519.pm
index 686b706..d9c2b3d 100644
--- a/lib/Crypt/Curve25519.pm
+++ b/lib/Crypt/Curve25519.pm
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 package Crypt::Curve25519;
+our $VERSION = 0.06;
 #ABSTRACT: Generate shared secret using elliptic-curve Diffie-Hellman function

 use strict;
```